# 'no resource identifier found for attribute 'textcolor' in package 'android''

Tags: android

When creating my hello android app, I am getting an error:

> 'no resource identifier found for attribute 'textcolor' in package
>   'android''

I am a complete newb to android development and I thought that I must have put in the wrong https in the location field when building my ADT, but from what I can see on [this site](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/), I did the right one. What or where to I go or do to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try textColor (capital 'C')?

Comment: can you please post the code that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
android:textColor="#ffff0000"
```

Note the capital 'C'. If this doesn't work you might also check the `xmlns` attribute on your xml root element. It should be:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```